# Where I can find startupApacheTomcat7.txt?

Tags: java, eclipse, azure, tomcat7

I was following [Azure Tutorial](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Developing-a-Hello-World-Java-Application-and-Deploying-it-in-Windows-Azure2.aspx) and one of the step asked me to copy from startupApacheTomcat7.txt and paste into startup.cmd. Appreciate if someone tell me where I can find the startupApacheTomcat7.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the Windows Azure project, there should be a Samples folder created for you, with sample deployment scripts for each web server:

[image: Windows Azure project with sample scripts]

At this point, you can open any of the sample txt files, copy the contents, and paste it into startup.cmd, where you'll then modify and customize it for your own use, including things such as war file name and server directory name.